# Qt + Visual Studio 2010: dependencies not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, add-in

I’m experiencing a problem and I’d like to know if someone else does.

I use Qt 4.8.0 Commercial for VS2010 + Qt Add-in 1.1.10 + VS2010.

Everything is fine, except that when I create in VS2010 a “Setup Project” and add to it the output of the Qt project, the dependecies of the output (QtCore, QtGui, even VC100_CRT) are not found nor updated.

There’s something strange happening to the Primary Output of the Qt project: for instance, in the “File System” window of the Setup project I can see the Primary Output icon, but if I right click on it I cannot create a shortcut to it (the option is missing).
If I build the whole thing, I get an .msi installer with only the bare .exe file.

The funny thing is that I if import a previous Qt project from VS2008 to VS2010, there is no problem at all: previous Setup projects continue to work great, and new Setup projects connected to existing Qt projects work fine as well.

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you found a solution to creating the shortcut.  When I right-click on mine, I can't select a shortcut too.  In the end, I've resorted to adding the compiled exe (rather than the primary output) and then I can create a shortcut to that.  For the dependencies, I just added them in manually.  Perhaps you've done the same.  It's really weird.  I'm using VS2010 also.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I haven't find any solutions other than the same workaround of yours. It's so weird... :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, The problem is with output path of the Primary output. See the property of the "Primary" project. Go to

> "Linker->General->Output"

Here you will see the value

> $(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).exe

That's where the problem lies. Change it to

> $(OutDir)$(ProjectName).exe

**(Remove the backslash)**.

Rebuild the complete project. Now add it to the setup project. Dependencies would be found fine now. No shortcut problem too.

> $(OutDir)

already contains a backslash. So appending another confuses it and the output exe is not found. Hence neither dependencies are detected, nor shortcut is allowed.